# Visual Studio 2015 Preview - Grunt and Bower Integration

Tags: visual-studio, gruntjs, bower, visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

In the ASP vNext templates there is, as announced, a nice and clean Grunt and Bower integration.

Since this integration is announced as a Visual Studio feature, is there an easy way of using this same integration in other projects like Cordova Apps?

Comment: just so you know, integration, even in asp.net project is not yet that 'integrated'. is more like a work in progress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Grunt and Bower integration is currently only available for ASP.NET projects.  You can post your vote [on Visual Studio UserVoice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6739957-bring-also-bower-grunt-love-to-apache-cordova-app) for adding this support to Cordova projects in VS. In the meantime Grunt and Bower can be used from the command line with Cordova projects.